# Wiring 4 gang box

Tags: electrical, lighting, wire

I habe done some renovations in my bedroom/bathroom and while doing so I had to remove the 4 gang box for the lights in my bathroom. Now I'm in the process of hooking the switches back up to the power and thought I got it done but I was wrong. 
So I have 4 switches;

1. Main lights- above bathroom mirror
2. Shower light
3. Bathtub light
4. Heat lamps

Each switch should work individually and the heat lamps do I believe I hooked that switch correctly. Problem is switches 2 and 3 only work if switch 1 is on. Now they only thing I was confused with were the 3 sets of wires coming up through the floor from the breaker. I know one is for the heat lamps leaving 2. I thought the other 2 sets were for bringing the power up and the other is to continue the power back somewhere else since the 3rd set of wires are not hot when all breakers are on. So what I did was connected the 3rd set with the 2nd set so essentially it would continue the circuit to wherever it continues to. Obviously I'm doing it all wrong can someone please assist me [image: heat lamps and shower light][image: 4 switches far left is heat lamp switch next is tub,then shower, and main light is switch on far right and below are the 3 sets wire and noticeable the 2 sets that are in question][image: main mirror lights and to the right is the tub light]
[image]

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/125829/47125) helpful.   The trick is colored tape.

Comment: @Harper the problem is not figuring out what wire power which light it's the wires beneath the box coming from the breaker. 2 out of the 3 carry power to the gang box while the 3rd does not. Initially I thought the 3rd wire was to carry the power back out the gang box and on to somewhere else that needed power. By thinking that I added that wire into my pigtails that were made when powering all switches

Comment: If you follow the color code idea for the wiring that Harper linked to you will probably figure it out, I say this because 1 switch controlling the others means the common hot is wrong that's why when sw1 is on the others now have power. His explanation is easy to follow+

Comment: I might get around to a better answer later, but generally speaking, none of the switches should feed into each other (unless you *want* to enforce a global on-off with subcomponent switches). It sounds like switches 2 and 3 are being fed from switch 1.

Comment: Let me better explain and hopefully it will help give a better picture. The wire coming from the panel was connected with the other wire that I think goes on to power other outlets or lights as well as 3 pigtails, one for each of the 3 switches. (4th/last switch is wired for the Heat lamps and is working correctly). After connecting the 3 pigtails and the separate continuing wire to the panel wire with a wire nut I then proceeded to wire the 3 switches by plugging them into the bottom wire hole of the switches. I plugged all the wires going to the desired fixtures into the top hole of the

Comment: Switches. All neutrals were connected already and wire nutted together as well as the ground wires were grounded as well. So essentially all I did was turn the hot black panel wire and turned it into 3 panel wires and connected the wires to the 3 switches. This is why I'm so confused on why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @HariGanti Let me better explain and hopefully it will help give a better picture. The wire coming from the panel was connected with the other wire that I think goes on to power other outlets or lights as well as 3 pigtails, one for each of the 3 switches. (4th/last switch is wired for the Heat lamps and is working correctly). After connecting the 3 pigtails and the separate continuing wire to the panel wire with a wire nut I then proceeded to wire the 3 switches by plugging them into the bottom wire hole of the switches. I plugged all the wires going to the desired fixtures into the top hole

Comment: @HariGanti Switches. All neutrals were connected already and wire nutted together as well as the ground wires were grounded as well. So essentially all I did was turn the hot black panel wire and turned it into 3 panel wires and connected the wires to the 3 switches. This is why I'm so confused on why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you pull all the switches out of the box and post a picture that shows how all the wires are connected?

Comment: @mark I could pull out but honestly, there are so many wires I'm pretty sure it's going to be very hard if not impossible to follow. better yet I can pull apart and take a picture of the black wires and how they were connected. Will that work?

Comment: @J.Monte - yes, assuming that all neutrals are tied together and not wired to any switches, and that there are no red wires.

Comment: Those white cables are actually called **cables** and contain more than one wire.  I can't see a single thing wrong with how you wired it, though the double switch on the left has me a little confused.  I am concerned with how you are splitting the always-hot, but it sounds like you are pigtailing which is hard to mess up.

Comment: @Harper the double switch has its own cable going to it and coming from it is the normal red, black, white, and bare. let me ask you could it have anything to do with the connection of the ground wires?

Comment: All the ground wires should be tied togethe.  All the neutrals should NOT.  Neutrals from supply circuit 1 and to its loads should be kept rigidly separate from neutrals from any other circuit.

Comment: @harper so your saying keep the neutral wire that feeds the 3 switches separate from the neutral that feeds the double switch? and for the ground wires coming from the light fixtures to the switches connect those to the switches but the ground from the panel gets connected where?

Comment: @Harper  I'm going to upload picture here in a minute of the switches wiring as soon as I can get them exposed again

Comment: @J.Monte Sorry, but for me, describing the wiring isn't really helping. I'm more of a visual guy. If you can, it'd be awesome to see a drawing (it can be done by hand, in MS Paint, Photoshop, literally whatever) because that maps out all the connections for us.

Comment: DV only because this has been abandoned and that will prevent it from being bumped to the top every few months.

Answer (score 0):

There should be one cable that is the hot feed from the panel. All the others are switch legs to the equipment.

It sounds like you somehow fed switches 2 and 3 through switch 1.

All of the switches should be fed with the same hot from the main panel cable. All of the neutrals should be tied together through to the equipment. Each switch leg would then go to each piece of equipment after its respective switch.

Good luck!

Comment: Let me better explain and hopefully it will help give a better picture. The wire coming from the panel was connected with the other wire that I think goes on to power other outlets or lights as well as 3 pigtails, one for each of the 3 switches. (4th/last switch is wired for the Heat lamps and is working correctly). After connecting the 3 pigtails and the separate continuing wire to the panel wire with a wire nut I then proceeded to wire the 3 switches by plugging them into the bottom wire hole of the switches. I plugged all the wires going to the desired fixtures into the top hole of the

Comment: Switches. All neutrals were connected already and wire nutted together as well as the ground wires were grounded as well. So essentially all I did was turn the hot black panel wire and turned it into 3 panel wires and connected the wires to the 3 switches. This is why I'm so confused on why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Well, depending on the rest of his wiring scheme, it's possible that two sets of cables come from the panel. In my house, all the lights are on an isolated circuit to prevent a receptacle/outlet from tripping a breaker and turning off the lights. If this is true, then the heat lamps might be on a different circuit due to their current requirements, especially since it all looks like 14/2 to me.